# Project Help I Am A Beginner At CustomTkinter and am just learning the basics

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, customtkinter

when i try to place frames with grid in a loop i keep having issues the frame skips the last frame on the second column? need help heres my code

```
import customtkinter as ctk
from mycalender import Calender

calender = Calender()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1000, 600
ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("green")
win = ctk.CTk()
win.geometry("1000x600")
win.title("")

frame = ctk.CTkFrame(win)
frame.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=5, pady=5)

frames = []
for day in range(31):
    frames.append(ctk.CTkFrame(frame, width=(WIDTH / 7) - 3, height=(HEIGHT / 5) - 3, corner_radius=5))

rowx, columny= 0, 0
for f in frames:
    f.grid(row=rowx, column=columny, padx=1, pady=1)
    if rowx == 4:
        rowx = 0
        columny += 1
    else:
        rowx += 1

win.mainloop()
```

i tried to change the padding and side of the frames but no luck not sure what i am doing wrong, i am a beginner

Answer (score 0):

**modify the loop to iterate from 0 to 5 inclusive.This wil ensure last frame in the second column (index 5) is being created.**

```
import customtkinter as ctk

root = ctk.CTk()

num_rows = 3

num_columns = 2

for i in range(num_rows * num_columns + 1):

    frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=root)

    frames.append(frame)

for i, frame in enumerate(frames):

    row = i // num_columns

    column = i % num_columns

    frame.grid(row=row, column=column, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

root.geometry("1000x600")

root.mainloop()
```